# How do I add an event handler to catch when a Window docks to the screen?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, docking

I have a method that takes in the height and width of the window when the WindowState changes with Window.StateChanged, but when I use the MS Windows docking to dock the Window, the application detects the change, runs the Event Handler, then docks and gives me the wrong height/width of the window.

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      Window.StateChanged += new EventHandler(Window_StateChanged);
 }

 void Window_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.WindowHeight = Application.Current.MainWindow.Height - EnvironmentalVariables.MENUBARHEIGHT;
      EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.WindowWidth = Application.Current.MainWindow.Width - EnvironmentalVariables.TREEWIDTH - 55;
 }
```

Manual State Changing

- Window State changes
- Window_StateChanged() called

Using Windows UI Docking

- Window_StateChanged() called
- Window State changes

How do I make it so that the event handler will run *after* the docking occurs?

To make it clear, I'm not using a referenced Windows Docking, I'm using the Operating System docking in Windows 7 where you drag to a side of the screen and it docks for you.

Comment: Have you tried to use [SizeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx) event instead of StateChanged?

Comment: This was a bolted-on feature in the Windows 7 shell.  There is no notification for it, all you can possibly observe is the location and size of the window changing.  It is then up to you to figure out that it happened by Aero snapping the window or the user positioning it just right.  There's no difference.  Which largely means you should not care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you tried ActualHeight\ActualWidth ?

Edit: (moved the answer here)
the 'SizeChanged' event is called after 'StateChanged' and the size should be fine then
you can update the size there

Comment: Yup. When I was debugging it, ActualHeight is the current height of the Window, and Height is the height of the Window after the Window State change, but when the Microsoft Windows UI docks the Window both Height and Actual Height are the same. Same applies for ActualWidth and Width.

Comment: the 'SizeChanged event' is called after 'StateChanged' and the size should be fine then

Comment: Interesting, when you use the Aero docking, the Actual[Height|Width] Size changes, but the Height|Width don't. Which is weird, because for regular Window State change, its the opposite values. I ended up having to check against WindowState.Maximized and then check if the [Height|Width] where bigger than the Actual[Height|Width] and set it accordingly.